# Sorting a txt-file in a descending order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sorting

I have a text file with two columns. 
I want to sort this file in a descending order, based on the second column.

In the following example, I have tree rows and two columns.
So my input is the following array:

```
 array([['A', 82512.09],
        ['B', 4036.5],
        ['C', 1187798.0]])
```

My output that I want to achieve is:

```
  array([['C', 1187798.0],
         ['A', 82512.09],
         ['B', 4036.5]])
```

Is there an efficient way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance,

Steven

Comment: What will be the format of the data? Will it be like 
 array([['A', 82512.09],
           ['B', 4036.5],
           ['C', 1187798.0]]) 
 or just the columns 
 
 'A', 82512.09
 'B', 4036.5
 'C', 1187798.0  Also will there be commas and quotation marks?

Comment: look at the `sorted` docs.

Comment: I did! @Vaibhav gusain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` has some nice features to help your sorting. You can define a key via `lambda` and finally reverse the order to sort in descending order.

Have a look at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
mylist = [['A', 82512.09], ['B', 4036.5], ['C', 1187798.0]]
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda second_col: second_col[1], reverse=True)

# output: [['C', 1187798.0], ['A', 82512.09], ['B', 4036.5]]
```

Comment: umm... `df = pd.DataFrame(result)`? I'm not too familiar with pandas, but that seems like a very very ... very basic question to ask.

Comment: That's not the point. Your question is related to the sorting of an array or list. Which understandably can cause trouble if you are not experienced. Converting lists into dataframes is more like a Google-thing in my opinion. Glad I could help though